# Typescript - How to handle generic data type with runtime type information

Tags: typescript

I have a generic container type that may contain different types of data. The type of the data contained is constrained at runtime by a "type" field that contains a string:

```js
type Type = "Numeric" | "Text";

type DataTypeFor<T extends Type> =
    T extends "Numeric" ? number
    : T extends "Text" ? string
    : never;

interface Container<T extends Type> {
    type: T;
    data: DataTypeFor<T>;
}
```

However, when we want to operate on an instance of this interface, the compiler is unable to infer the correct type of the `data` field:

```js
function operate<T extends Type>(container: Container<T>) {
    switch (container.type) {
        case "Numeric":
            // Error
            const a: number = container.data;
            console.log(a);
            break;
        case "Text":
            // Error
            const b: string = container.data;
            console.log(b);
            break;
        case "Fsasefsef":
            // No error here! Why?
            break;
    }
}
```

I must have a slightly incorrect idea about how type inference works with generics in instances like these.

Is there any way to achieve the pattern that I want here?

[Typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oCIByBXAthATgSwGNkoAfFGCAD2GQG4AoUSKAEQENg25IAxAexwAeGAD4oCelCmwoVYBAB2AEwDOKDNnxEoAfigKsAI1yTpALhlzFq8nOJ6VwfAoDmpqRYUQAbrgb08BXkcADM2AmgAYT4gtkDcYVlqazVuCDEAb3coJggLGAZpKCUONgt2TjT+IVEGAF96ehD0BQJgPBioPkgcDghEq2VU+BEACgIYznicC2jY6eERAEooLKKVAHc8YAIACyhxybivHAA6XJW1oukCNhVoNCxcQmQzbOvpAHpPqABRHBwAneHygEwUjigZX0Rlw4lBR2mpxKnEKIKKYJUfAANhBTli+C5Rmwlqi0VJDDgIGwANak663e62aivYEfb5-AFAsk3GIQwwWRzOFxwsFTE5I0p0tEY7G4-GEwwk1nXClU2nKhkPHgqO4QEL3EIs7lSdmoPiyTk4KC7XAQACEUAA6rsQDplUVVTS6Q06kA)

Comment: Does the type have to be defined as a string?

Comment: @Diesel I guess I'd accept an enum if necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve this pattern by using Discriminated Unions.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions

example:

```js
interface Numeric {
    type: "Numeric"
    data: number
}

interface Text {
    type: "Text"
    data: string
}

type Container = Numeric | Text

function operate(container: Container) {
    switch (container.type) {
        case "Numeric":
            const a: number = container.data;
            console.log(a);
            break;
        case "Text":
            const b: string = container.data;
            console.log(b);
            break;
    }
}
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC21gOQbwChkTkwBPABwgC5kAiDbKXe40gEzjDjpCwBG0QgF9ChUJFiIUAFQgAPMAXYkK1OvXlK2pZFx50AzmBYgA5qPHqUAYQD24OKGjIAvGiw48AH2TawcRh0EAQwYEdke2oobggACgRHHhcoOgcnVIBKFT0jAHdgMAQAC2RE5OcQaAA6GxyiPT0EOCMURi8WBHoaVSbmxxNkXmR+TCEod2QkzOqoGoM4AG4+-pIZo3sAGwgarftzeLgslbWmgSgIOABrU7WWtoYAntX7weUBY1NQcymZlLmC24y1e-Q2212+0OAhOoPOlxudxIYhEQA